# not able to see the view after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Hi I have got a drop downlist that I am binding that one in controller I have got one button in view with that I am doing some validations that's working fine,

when I submit the button for validation check i am not able to get the view with error message. Instead of this I am getting  error like this **" The view 'PostValues' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations".**
would any one help on why I am not able to get the view
here the view is strongly Typed view 
and this is my code in controller.

```
public class CrossFieldsTxtboxesController : Controller
{
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = NewMethod();              
            return View(model);
        }    
        private static CrossFieldValidation NewMethod()
        {
            var model = new CrossFieldValidation
            {
                SelectedValue = "Amount",
                Items = new[]
                {
                     new SelectListItem { Value = "Amount", Text = "Amount" },
                     new SelectListItem { Value = "Pound", Text = "Pound" },
                     new SelectListItem { Value = "Percent", Text = "Percent" },
                }    
            };
            return model;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostValues(CrossFieldValidation model1)
        {               
            model1 =  NewMethod();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {    
                return View(model1);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");                       
            }                                               
        }    
    }
```

and this is my view

```
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.CrossFieldValidation   
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostValues", "CrossFieldsTxtboxes"))
{   
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class ="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TxtCrossField)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.TxtCrossField)
    </div>    
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.SelectedValue , Model.Items)
     <input id="PostValues" type="Submit" value="PostValues" />
}
```

would any one pls help on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
return View(model1);
```

looks for the view named exactly like the action in which it was called. Calling this line from `PostValues` action assumes there is a view `PostValues.cshtml` (which apparently does not exist). If you still want to use view `Index` - you should specify this explicitly:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{    
    return View("Index", model1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Andrei said. Alternatively, you can give your PostValues method an additional tag:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult PostValues(CrossFieldValidation model1)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {    
        return View(model1);
    }
}
```